# replace custom match pattern and replace matched patent and give inside string in vscode with regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

consider,I have a string `"!{saveSummary}!"`.

Now i have to replace `"!`  `!"`, and retrive string inside pattern `"!`  `!"`  , which is `{saveSummary}` in vscode. Is there any convenient way to do this for every string, which match this pattern.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Find

```
"!([^"]*)!"
```

Replace

```
$1
```

If there is a possibility there is a single `"` between the pattern you can use a non-greedy `*`

Find

```
"!(.*?)!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a **RegExp** with a **global** flag set on. Since regex currently does not allow mixing global and groups functionality use [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```js
var str = 'The quick "!{foo}!" brown fox jumps"!{bar}!" over the lazy dog "!{baz}!"';
var re = /\"\!([\S]+)\!\"/g;
var arr;
while (arr = re.exec(str)) {
  console.log(arr[1]);
}
```

### VSCode

For VSCode:

1. Make sure to turn the Use Regular Expression (Alt+R) on
2. Use this pattern: `("!)([\S]+)(!")`
3. Replace with what you need.

Use `$1something-new$3` to update it with what you aim for.

In this case:

- `$1` == `"!`
- `$2` == `saveSummary`
- `$3` == `!"`

$N is a N-th group (inside braces `()`). So adjust your query accordingly if you need to.

[image]

Comment: thanks for help, last issue before accept. can you please tell me a way to write macro for vs code.